# Why do I keep getting an error when I try to resize ext4 under extended?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I had already assigned unallocated space to my extended partition and now i want to enlarge my ext4 partition. The problem is, it starts and when its almost finished, it gives me an error and makes me save a data file. I tried looking for a solution on this and the gparted forums, Bugzilla and Ubuntu forums but couldn't find any. Please tell me how i can extend my ext4 file. the unallocated spaces is 2GB to the left of the partition in the the extended partition.
[Saved Details information](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=521c710530&view=att&th=1425f1ac8e87c100&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_ho2c8g3q1&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_Ch0K85GDjshC_Lg5lllrf&sadet=1384606295537&sads=LnJVb-nsJP9yUH2Pp1-bKMolGXo)
[Image of error since i dont have any credits](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=521c710530&view=att&th=1425f1ac8e87c100&attid=0.2&disp=inline&realattid=f_ho2c86u90&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_Ch0K85GDjshC_Lg5lllrf&sadet=1384606722693&sads=jilPN3r55Rwa2Im-0emO9c91N6g)

Comment: Your links don't work... just gives Error 404 server error -they are also annoying in that you need a Google account to log in first. Anyway, if you can access your computer, you should be able to [install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) and [run GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/documentation.php) to edit the partition, without having to use a Live CD. However, always be careful and backup first, as this will probably wipe any data on the partition.

Answer (score 0):

you doesn't able to add extra space to your ubuntu ext4 partition when it was mounted.When you boot into `ubuntu os`,the ubuntu partition was automatically mounted.So boot [`gparted-live`disk](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) and then add `2gb unused space` to your ext4 partition.